# Primefaces datatable, item on multiple rows

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I can not find a primefaces datatable example on how to make one item to be shown on two (or more) rows.
I need to show an item in a datatable about like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Text 1 from entry</td>
    <td>Text 2 from entry</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Text 3 from entry</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Can it be done or should I use some other tag to render like this?

I tried:

```
...xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"...

<p:dataTable var="item" value="#{bean.items}">
  <p:column>
    <p:row>
      <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.title}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.shortText}" />
      </p:column>
    </p:row>
    <p:row>
      <p:column colspan="2">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.longText}" />
      </p:column>
    </p:row>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

But obviously this is wrong and/or I have misunderstood the concept of using 'p:row'. I can not find any explanation on how to do this properly, so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you want to use the [`<p:panelGrid>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml) component that can achieve this functionality easily?

Basic example:

```
<p:panelGrid>
    <p:row>
        <p:column>Text 1 from entry</p:column>
        <p:column>Text 2 from entry</p:column>
    </p:row>
    <p:row>
        <p:column colspan="2">Text 3 from entry</p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

That embedded, we have:

```
<p:dataTable var="item" value="#{bean.items}">
    <p:column>
        <p:panelGrid>
            <p:row>
                <p:column><h:outputText value="#{item.title}" /></p:column>
                <p:column><h:outputText value="#{item.shortText}" /></p:column>
            </p:row>
            <p:row>
                <p:column colspan="2"><h:outputText value="#{item.longText}" /></p:column>
            </p:row>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Exactly. I knew there's a proper way, but couldn't find how to do it.